# Select multiple values from the same row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a script and I want to return 5 values from the database that have the same category but it is only returning one. Any ideas?

Here's the script:

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT Category FROM GameData
        WHERE Title=\"$title\" ");
//returns category to search in next select
    $row= mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT Title FROM GameData
    WHERE Category=\"$row[0]\" LIMIT 5 ");
    $rows= mysql_fetch_array($results);
    print_r($rows); //returns $title from first select query
```

I'm new to databases and MySQL so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest you use something like PHP PDO instead of mysql_x. It's newer, provides db abstraction and with prepared statements you can prevent sql injection

Comment: Your code is unfortunately not efficient, if you are new to databases, learn them from beginning in right way. Use join's.

Answer (score 4):

`mysql_fetch_array` just fetch one row in one call use loop to fetch multiple records

```
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($results))
{

    print_r($row); //returns $title from first select query
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You must loop over all the results: `mysql_fetch_array` returns *one result row*, so you have to call it multiple times:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    // here process ONE row
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Thought it might be something with a loop but haven't used any loop in php other than the for loop so didn't know what to use. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

[**`mysql_fetch_array`**](http://fr.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) will only fetch **one** row : if you want to fetch several rows, **you'll have to call `mysql_fetch_array` several times** -- in a loop, typically.

For a couple of examples, you can take a look at [**its manual page**](http://fr.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) ; but, in your case, you'll probably want to use something like this :

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT Title FROM GameData
    WHERE Category='...' LIMIT 5 ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    // work with $row['Title']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

mysql_fetch_array only returns one row, you would have to loop through the rows

see example at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 1):

You should use following query in order to make things right.

```
 SELECT `Title` FROM GameData 
 LEFT JOIN
 Category ON Category.Id = GameData.Category
 WHERE Category.Title = "$title" LIMIT 5
```

I assumed that Category has column Id. 
I advise you to learn about [JOINS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html). 
Additionally, you may want to rename **Category** to Category_Id, and drop letter-case so Category would become **category_id**.